# Mod for Minecraft using Eclipse gets error when running

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I made a tool from a block I made no errors in code. When I try to click build it gives me this terminal error:
How can i fix this? Please.
Here is the code for the RecipesTools.addRecipes

```
package net.minecraft.src;

public class RecipesTools
{
    private String recipePatterns[][] =
    {
        {
            "XXX", " # ", " # "
        }, {
            "X", "#", "#"
        }, {
            "XX", "X#", " #"
        }, {
            "XX", " #", " #"
        }
    };
    private Object recipeItems[][];

    public RecipesTools()
    {
        recipeItems = (new Object[][]
                {
                    new Object[] {
                        Block.planks, Block.cobblestone, Item.ingotIron, Item.diamond, Item.ingotGold,  Block.RadiatedStone
                    }, new Object[] {
                        Item.pickaxeWood, Item.pickaxeStone, Item.pickaxeSteel, Item.pickaxeDiamond, Item.pickaxeGold, Item.pickaxeRadiated
                    }, new Object[] {
                        Item.shovelWood, Item.shovelStone, Item.shovelSteel, Item.shovelDiamond, Item.shovelGold
                    }, new Object[] {
                        Item.axeWood, Item.axeStone, Item.axeSteel, Item.axeDiamond, Item.axeGold
                    }, new Object[] {
                        Item.hoeWood, Item.hoeStone, Item.hoeSteel, Item.hoeDiamond, Item.hoeGold
                    }
                });
    }

    public void addRecipes(CraftingManager craftingmanager)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < recipeItems[0].length; i++)
        {
            Object obj = recipeItems[0][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < recipeItems.length - 1; j++)
            {
                Item item = (Item)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
                craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(item), new Object[]
                        {
                            recipePatterns[j], Character.valueOf('#'), Item.stick, Character.valueOf('X'), obj
                        });
            }
        }

        craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Item.shears), new Object[]
                {
                    " #", "# ", Character.valueOf('#'), Item.ingotIron
                });
    }
}
```

*EDIT*
I also have given Eclipe 1024mb of RAM and deleted my .Minecraft folder.

```
CONFLICT @ 22
27 achievements
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraft.src.StatList.initCraftableStats(StatList.java:74)
    at net.minecraft.src.StatList.initBreakableStats(StatList.java:55)
    at net.minecraft.src.Block.<clinit>(Block.java:975)
    at net.minecraft.src.TextureWaterFX.<init>(TextureWaterFX.java:13)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:205)
    at net.minecraft.src.MinecraftImpl.<init>(MinecraftImpl.java:13)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startMainThread(Minecraft.java:1984)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startMainThread1(Minecraft.java:1970)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.main(Minecraft.java:2032)
    at Start.main(Start.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at net.minecraft.src.RecipesTools.addRecipes(RecipesTools.java:44)
    at net.minecraft.src.CraftingManager.<init>(CraftingManager.java:19)
    at net.minecraft.src.CraftingManager.<clinit>(CraftingManager.java:8)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

`recipeItems[0].length` is 6. But `recipeItems[2]` and the following only have five elements. Your toplevel loop in `addRecipes` it therefore wrong.

You should probably be using collection types (vector, list, `Array`, ...) and iterators for this, would make the code safer and more readable (IMO).

Comment: I was trying to explain why my collection types are the way they are

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop in `addRecipies` is iterating over the `[0]` array of `recipeItems`.  In the first child array, there are 6 elements meaning that `recipeItems[0][5]` will be a valid item.  But there is an incorrect assumption that this is true for all `recipeItems` arrays.  At least one of the later arrays has fewer than 6 elements.

You should be iterating over the size of the child arrays rather than the size of the first array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably check of what type the `Object`s in the array are, before you cast them, so the part which currently is

```
Item item = (Item)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
```

in the loop, should be replaced with something like this:

```
Object itemObj = recipeItems[j + 1][i];
if(itemObj instanceof Item)
{
    // The current element is an Item
    Item item = (Item)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
    craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(item), new Object[]
    {
        recipePatterns[j], Character.valueOf('#'), Item.stick, Character.valueOf('X'), obj
    });
}
else if(itemObj instanceof Block)
{
    // The current element is a Block
    Block block = (Block)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
    craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(block), new Object[]
    {
        recipePatterns[j], Character.valueOf('#'), Item.stick, Character.valueOf('X'), obj
    });
}
else
{
    // The current element is none of the types above
    // TODO Throw an exception, print a message or quit the game
}
```

because, I'm pretty sure you can't cast an `Item` to a `Block`. This will not fix this problem, that was just a tip, because the code you used there before may cause errors in the future.

The solution to your current problem is what *Mat* and *nicholas.hauschild* has already answered. The first two elements of the `recipeItems` array (`recipeItems[0]` and `recipeItems[1]`) have 6 elements, but the rest of the elements have only 5 elements. In your loop, you only take the length of the first element and use it to loop through the rest of the elements too, but they are smaller than the first.
What happens if you try to acces element 6 in an array with 5 elements?

You could replace the loop with something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < recipeItems.length - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < recipeItems[i].length; j++)
    {
        Object obj = recipeItems[0][j];
        Object itemObj = recipeItems[i + 1][j];
        if(itemObj instanceof Item)
        {
            // The current element is an Item
            Item item = (Item)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
            craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(item), new Object[]
            {
                recipePatterns[j], Character.valueOf('#'), Item.stick, Character.valueOf('X'), obj
            });
        }
        else if(itemObj instanceof Block)
        {
            // The current element is a Block
            Block block = (Block)recipeItems[j + 1][i];
            craftingmanager.addRecipe(new ItemStack(block), new Object[]
            {
                recipePatterns[j], Character.valueOf('#'), Item.stick, Character.valueOf('X'), obj
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // The current element is none of the types above
            // TODO Throw an exception, print a message or quit the game
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!